# Score update script not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been following the [Unity 2D Catch Game Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFzT17M1Xxs).

It's a bit outdated but most of the stuff is the same. The score script starts at 40:30 in the video.

I've created the text `Score: ??` and I've created the script too, however when I run the game it just stays at `Score: .` And nothing else, no score, no question marks, nothing, doesn't update either.

I have a feeling this may be due to the new `GetComponent` stuff in Unity that wasn't there before but I'm not too sure.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text ScoreText;
    private int score;

// Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        score = 0;
        UpdateScore();
        //ScoreText = ScoreText.GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(){
        score = score + 1;
        UpdateScore();
    }

    void UpdateScore(){
        ScoreText.text = "Score:\n" + score;
    }
}
```

I tried using what's been commented as well, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: are you reaching OnTriggerEnter2D?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the score to be dispayed like this:

```
Score: 0
```

then remove the new line (`\n`) character from the "Score" string. It should be:

```
void UpdateScore()
{
        ScoreText.text = "Score: " + score;
}
```

If you want the score to be displayed like this:

```
Score:
0
```

Then see csalzman's answer.

Comment: Perfect. I can't believe I didn't realise that. Worked like a charm.

Comment: @FShiwani Ace, remember to accept the answer if it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Check the vertical overflow on your Text component. I'd bet the score is there, but hidden due to it being set to Truncate rather than Overflow.